# How to create the gradle in Intellij?

Tags: jsp, gradle, intellij-idea

recently, I'm studying jsp with Gradle. And all the references are showing that able to create the project with Gradle. but in my IntelliJ isn't able to create the project with Gradle[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqc5X.png). I downloaded Gradle on my PC and set up already. can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Click on "New Project". Gradle is one of the build system options.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create it with IntelliJ, instead you can run `gradle init` on the command line in the directory where you want your project. This will create the project for you, which can then be imported in IntelliJ.

Here is a tutorial from [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/marco-codes-gradle/new-projects-gradle-init/)

Alternatively, you can use the unofficial [gradle-initializr](https://gradle-initializr.cleverapps.io/) that is based on the same idea as [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io), but for plain gradle projects. It is basically a web version of `gradle init` which will give you the project in a `.zip` file.

---

Edit: As Dave Newton pointed out you can select `Gradle` as a build system. This options is available for the plain project as well as other supported project types.

[image]

Comment: New projects have a build system option, of which Gradle is one.